Why is my custom CSS not being applied to a progress bar in my JSP page?
I have a JSP page where I'm trying to implement a progress bar to display the order status (e.g., "Pending", "Confirmed", "Shipping", "Delivered"). However, my custom CSS is not being applied, even though I have used !important in several places to override other styles. I suspect the issue might be due to other styles (like from Bootstrap or other frameworks) overriding my CSS.
I have added !important to override Bootstrap styles, but it still doesn't work.
I have checked the HTML and confirmed that the classes are being rendered correctly.
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="/common/taglib.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="vi">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Trạng thái đơn hàng</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    /* CSS cho step progress bar */
    .order-status-container {
      display: flex !important;
      justify-content: space-between !important;
      align-items: center !important;
    }

    .order-status-step {
      text-align: center !important;
      position: relative !important;
      flex: 1 !important;
    }

    .order-status-step::before {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 6px;
      background-color: #e0e0e0 !important;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .order-status-step.active::before {
      background-color: #28a745 !important;
    }

    .order-status-line {
      background-color: #e0e0e0 !important;
      height: 6px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      width: 100%;
    }

    .order-status-step.active + .order-status-step .order-status-line {
      background-color: #28a745 !important;
    }

    .progress-step span {
      display: block;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center mt-5" style="padding-top: 60px;">Trạng thái đơn hàng</h2>

  <div class="order-status-container">
    <div class="order-status-step ${userOrder.orderState >= 0 ? 'active' : ''}">
      <div class="order-status-line"></div>
      <span>Chờ xử lý</span>
    </div>
    <div class="order-status-step ${userOrder.orderState >= 1 ? 'active' : ''}">
      <div class="order-status-line"></div>
      <span>Đã xác nhận</span>
    </div>
    <div class="order-status-step ${userOrder.orderState >= 2 ? 'active' : ''}">
      <div class="order-status-line"></div>
      <span>Đang giao hàng</span>
    </div>
    <div class="order-status-step ${userOrder.orderState >= 3 ? 'active' : ''}">
      <div class="order-status-line"></div>
      <span>Đã nhận hàng</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
//library 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

I have cleared the browser cache and tried reloading the page multiple times.

I think you can get rid of all "order-status-line" if you use the :before option to do the progress bar, they are overlapping. Use the browser inspection tool to see where are your elements and what styles are applying to them.
I suppose you also want the next item to be green, so replace this:
.order-status-step.active + .order-status-step .order-status-line {
    background-color: #28a745 !important;
}

To this:
.order-status-step.active + .order-status-step:before {
    background-color: #28a745 !important;
}

Also, you should not use !important that easy, try looking the CSS Specificity.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
